# How to scatter objects only on the topmost faces of the topmost layer of voxels of a multi-layered voxel grid?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: voxelizing a cylinder with geometry nodes]

I created a geometry node setup that "voxelizes" objects using the 'mesh to volume' and 'distribute points in volume' nodes, the voxels are instances of a '1m x 1m x 1m' cube which are instanced there using the 'instances on points' node.

[image: the voxelizer]

The logic of the voxelizer is not mine, see this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrEHoaq6QFE

Now I want to scatter objects only on the topmost faces of the topmost layer of voxels, like grass, mushrooms, flowers etc using the 'distribute points on faces' node.

[image: scattering objects on the topmost faces of voxels, but on every voxel, solid view]

Currently I have a "mask" put into the selection socket of the 'distribute points on faces' node that filters out faces with normals pointing elsewhere than up. It works but does this for every voxel not just the topmost layer of voxels.

[image: scattering objects on the topmost faces of voxels, but on every voxel, x-ray view]

My node setup using The voxelizer:

[image: scatter logic, using the voxelizer]

The "mask" zoomed in:

[image: the mask]

Any ideas on how to do this with geometry nodes? Is it even possible with the latest version of blender? I am using blender version 3.5.0. Thank you for your help!

Comment: since you didn't really show us a readable node tree and if you want to attract more people, i would suggest providing your blend file so we know what you have done. There is almost never a "general" solution but it depends how you did it.

Comment: For scattering objects, I used that "mask", which is readable, put it in the selection socket of the 'distribute points on faces' node, which works but for every voxel. As for the voxelizer, it is using the 'mesh to volume' and 'distribute points in volume' nodes like i stated, the voxels are instances of a 1mx1mx1m cube which are instanced there using the 'instances on points' node, that is it. I think the other nodes I used are not important to solve the problem. I think I was clear, I do not want to attract people who do not help just want my work..

Comment: But.. I used the logic from this video for the voxelizer if that helps: https://youtu.be/LrEHoaq6QFE

Comment: we all help here for free in our free time - so i would - if i ask a question - make it as easy as possible for those people who answer to attract more people...and yes, this is just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your voxels are instances, and instances don't have normals, so that is probably why your comparison on the normal doesn't work.

Add a *realize instances* node after the voxel node but before the distribute points on faces.

I would also recommend rename the output of your voxel node to *instance* instances of *geometry*, so it's more clear to you in the future.

Edit:
I think I'm wrong. What is actually going in is. You have multiple cube and each one has a top face pointing up and all of those are getting point on them.
I wasn't  completely wrong, though. I believe instances are all treated as their original geometry (before converted to an instance), so they all get the same point distribution and selection from the *dpof* node - I also suspect that even if you rotate the instances the face the was originally facing z up will still read as z up until realized.

side point:
a dot product is else wise multiplication of two vectors and adding up the results (meaning A.x × B.x + A.y × B.y + A.z × B.z), which in your case is the same as multiplying *z* by 1 and the rest by 0, so you might as well just use a separate xyz node.